# Should I weakify "local" variables used in a block?

Tags: ios, swift

This is not another question about `[weak self]`. This is about use of variables not contained by `self`, but rather by the wrapping function.

```
func someFunction(){
    someOtherFunction(completionBlock:{ [weak self] in
        self?.doStuff()
    })
}
```

As far as I understand, I need the `[weak self]` in order to prevent a retain cycle.

But what if I need to use a variable from the wrapping function, like this:

```
func someFunction(){
    let someVariable = MyObject()
    someOtherFunction(completionBlock:{ [weak self] in
        self?.doStuff(with: someVariable)
    })
}
```

This works, which makes me wonder.. How, and how long is `someVariable` held in memory? Can it create its own tiny retain cycle where my completion block strongly references the local `someVariable`? How will they be released? **Should** I add `[weak self, weak someVariable]` in the block? But then, won't `someVariable` be released immediately after I call `someOtherFunction`, because it's the end of this function - and the end of `someVariable`'s lifetime..?

I'm having trouble completely understanding references, and can't see how my `completionBlock` and `someVariable` will ever be released.. Are blocks even released?

Comment: @DávidPásztor That is nothing like my question. My question has nothing to do with `[weak self]`. Please read the question.

Comment: It actually does have to do quite a lot since you only have access to instance properties through self (even though you don't have to write that out explicitly unless in a closure), so there's no point in declaring an instance property weak inside a closure, since if you already use `[weak self]`, no instance property can cause a retain cycle

Comment: @DávidPásztor So the variable **in my function** named `someVariable` is retained by the `completionBlock` until the block is released by `someOtherFunction`? Sorry, but that is not answered in the linked duplicateOf, nor in any other [weak *] question I found when searching for this.

Comment: An instance variable cannot be retained, since it only exists as long as the instance that holds it exists. ARC counts the reference to __objects__ not instance variables, but since instance variables can only be accessed through their instances, code referring to the instance variables will indeed create a reference to the instance itself.

Comment: However, as I've already stated, `[weak self]` already gets rid of the problem of any instance variables retaining a reference to `self` since when using `[weak self]` you make `self` optional, hence by using optional chaining the variable won't even be accessed if `self` is `nil`. So to understand if an instance property can create a retain cycle or not, you essentially need to understand when to use `weak` or `unowned` self in a closure and when not to use any of them.

Comment: I'm getting confused by your use of `instance property`, `instance variable` and `object`. The `someVariable` **is** an object, it is **not** accessible from `self`, but it is **clearly** retained, as I am able to access it from my completionBlock even though the wrapping function `someFunction` is done. If I call `someFunction` twice, **two** instances of `MyObject` will be in their own `someVariable`, both retained by their corresponding block, but neither is accessible from `self`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor So the only explanation I have is that `someOtherFunction` is retaining `someVariable` in the `completionBlock` I send to it, and that `self` **can** be released because `someVariable` doesn't have a reference to `self` in any way. If `self` is released before the block is called, then `someVariable` will still exist in the retained completionBlock - and when the completionBlock is released `someVariable` will be released with it - meaning I don't have to weakify `someVariable`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any variable referenced inside a closure will be strongly retained by that closure. You can adjust that by including a *closure capture list* (e.g. `[weak self]`), which allows you to specify the particular memory management pattern of references captured in the closure.

```
func someFunction(){
    let someVariable = MyObject()
    someOtherFunction(completionBlock:{ [weak self] in
        self?.doStuff(with: someVariable)
    })
}
```

Here, `someVariable` is retained by the closure, as you have stated. In this case, it *has* to be, because nobody else cares about it. As you've mentioned in comments, if you used a capture list of `[weak someVariable]` then it would always be nil when the completion block executed, as it has gone out of scope in it's original function.

A "tiny retain cycle" isn't being created. A retain cycle has to be a *cycle* - that is, A holds a strong reference to B, which holds a strong reference to A. `someVariable` doesn't have references to anything.

Once `someOtherFunction` has finished with the reference to the completion closure, everything goes away. The closure is just another variable as far as `someOtherFunction` is concerned, and it will survive as long as it is in scope.

**Should I weakify “local” variables used in a block?** - no, as they will then be nil by the time the block comes to use them.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to mention not so clear option, what is very usual place to create retain cycle and where you should be aware of weaken variables.

Lets consider this situation:

```
func someFunction() {
    let object = Something()
    object.handler = { [weak self] in 
       self?.doStuff(with: object)
    }
}
```

Now there is retain cycle, and `object` cannot be deallocated until somebody manually unset the `handler`. Because now object strongify itself in the captured block.

So better solution is:

```
func someFunction() {
    let object = Something()
    object.handler = { [weak self, unowned object] in 
       self?.doStuff(with: object)
    }
}
```

And good practice is pass the `object` as argument in `handler`

```
func someFunction() {
    let object = Something()
    object.handler = { [weak self] (object) in 
       self?.doStuff(with: object)
    }
}
```

So signature of this should look like:

```
class Something {
    var handler:((Something) -> Void)?
    deinit {
        print("retain cycle is not here")
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great.  didn't know you can do [weak self, unowned someObject]